# Running function on Mapbox click marker // Displaying SVGs in position relative to Mapbox coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm creating an interactive website prototype for a travel-booking site, using mapbox for the first time. I've done a lot of searching through the mapbox site and elsewhere but there's here's a couple things I just can't figure out:

**First problem**: when a marker on the map is clicked, a js function should be run to reveal the pane on the right

[image: fig 1]

I already have this code from mapbox that opens an individual popup on each marker on click (I'll remove these popups later):

```
    // When a click event occurs near a place, open a popup at the location of
    // the feature, with description HTML from its properties.
    map.on('click', function (e) {
    var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, { layers: ['places'] });

    if (!features.length) {
        return;
    }

    var feature = features[0];

    // Populate the popup and set its coordinates
    // based on the feature found.
    var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
        .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
        .setHTML(feature.properties.description)
        .addTo(map);
    });
```

Based on how the clicking is handled in that example, I was hoping something along the line of this would work:

```
    feature.on('click', function (e) {
        **Insert code to display the pane here**
    });
```

But that does not work. It's harder to figure these things out when you're using an api you're not familiar with. So I need to know how I would do that.

**The second problem**: When the user clicks to look at popular trips through the city, a js function will run run to show svgs over the map (from an Illustrator mockup)

[image: fig 2]

The issue here is that I need the svg to display at certain coordinates of the map, not just a position in the screen. This, I have no idea where to start.

Any help is appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I didn't really understand your "first problem", but for the second problem, you can add an image at a given lat/lon using a Marker. See [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/).

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'marker';
    el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://placekitten.com/g/' + marker.properties.iconSize.join('/') + '/)';
    el.style.width = marker.properties.iconSize[0] + 'px';
    el.style.height = marker.properties.iconSize[1] + 'px';

    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        window.alert(marker.properties.message);
    });

    // add marker to map
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el, {offset: [-marker.properties.iconSize[0] / 2, -marker.properties.iconSize[1] / 2]})
        .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
        .addTo(map);
```

### Edit

I see from your comment you want the image to remain at the same scale with the map, when it zooms in and out. You want an [Image source](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#sources-image), not a marker.

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/image-on-a-map/

```
 "overlay": {
            "type": "image",
            "url": "https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/radar.gif",
            "coordinates": [
                [-80.425, 46.437],
                [-71.516, 46.437],
                [-71.516, 37.936],
                [-80.425, 37.936]
            ]
        }
```

It probably doesn't support SVG, however.

Comment: Thanks! I got the kitten to appear and was able to bind it to a click event which is what I want. However, I had trouble changing the image to my own svg image. I tried both local and uploaded versions, and got rid of the " + marker.properties.iconSize ... " code and the related code in the width and height-setting lines and the new marker line, but nothing showed. How would I get this to work?

Comment: Also, it it possible to prevent the image to scale on zoom? If not, I can try to work around that...

Comment: Oh, you want the image to be fixed with the map, and zoom with it? See my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand where to plug that code in.. The example has it in the setup of the mapStyle, but I want the overlay to appear on click like I was able to do with the first marker example.

Comment: Sorry, buddy. I think you're on your own from here. :)